# Need help with wireless USB adapter (Ourlink AC600) All ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, usb, adapter

I have sort of a problem, first I'd like to mention that I do not have internet access on my Linux OS, I do however have it on my windows and can transfer files via USB, thing is right, I found the drivers on the official website and it gives an install.sh file, I don't know how to run it (New to Linux) So I just copied the code from it and pasted it in the terminal, it doesn't work on a normal terminal so I have to go into SU, although even when I do that it gives me errors such as : Error missing xxx
Something like that
Here is the link if anyone needs the drivers
https://www.ourlink.us/collections/some/products/glam-hobby-600mbps-mini-802-11ac-dual-band-2-4g-5g-wireless-network-adapter-usb-wi-fi-dongle-adapter-with-2dbi-antenna-support-windows-xp-win-vista-win-7-win-8-1-win-10-mac-os-x-10-6-10-11-5

Big thing : Forgot.to mention that the specified.card is internal, while im trying to setup an external . USB wifi adapter

Would appreciate some help on how to install properly, ty!
EDIT : I know it says "Supports windows" And it doesn't say Linux at all, but there is a linux folder in the download, just thought I'd let you know

EDIT : I got it working! It was the most annoying thing ever... but for anyone else in my situation I will help you out right now. You need internet on linux (USB tether your phone or any way) or another pc with internet. With the internet download this :
https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux?gclid=CjwKCAjwranNBRBhEiwASu908IszYUcxISq8Z8WBjL6EXI-m1in4WJkGOq-pp7slEGYZe7PoQfvNMBoCvpoQAvD_BwE

Get the free trial as you will only need it once, also this should work for any official drivers for your card that uses a .exe

Get your drivers for your network card, look them up, in my case they were here for the OurLink ac600, which you could just look upon google or refer to the drivers I posted beforehand

Get both of them on to your Linux, install and open open crossover, Right click on the .exe of your driver and click "open with" then "run with crossover" and it will install just like Windows! Congrats, finally got it working....

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: It appears that the correct driver rt2800pci is already loaded.

Comment: If your question is about a USB dongle, post output of `lsusb` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working! It was the most annoying thing ever... but for anyone else in my situation I will help you out right now. You need internet on linux (USB tether your phone or any way) or another pc with internet. With the internet download this : https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux?gclid=CjwKCAjwranNBRBhEiwASu908IszYUcxISq8Z8WBjL6EXI-m1in4WJkGOq-pp7slEGYZe7PoQfvNMBoCvpoQAvD_BwE

Get the free trial as you will only need it once, also this should work for any official drivers for your card that uses a .exe

Get your drivers for your network card, look them up, in my case they were here for the OurLink ac600, which you could just look upon google or refer to the drivers I posted beforehand in the original post

Get both of them on to your Linux, install and open open crossover, Right click on the .exe of your driver and click "open with" then "run with crossover" and it will install just like Windows! Congrats, finally got it working....